# Efficiently concatenate many sas datasets

Tags: dataset, concatenation, sas

I have over 200k small datasets with the same variables (n<1000 and usually n<100) that I want to concatenate into a master dataset. I have tried using a macro that uses a data step to just iterate through all of the new datasets and concatenate with the master with "set master new:", but this is taking a really long time. Also, if I try to run at the same time, the call execute data step says that I am out of memory on a huge server box. For reference, all of the small datasets together are just over 5 Gigs. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

```
%macro catDat(name, nbr) ;
    /*call in new dataset */
    data new ;
    set libin.&name ;
    run ;

    /* reorder names */
    proc sql noprint;
    create table new as 
    select var1, var2, var3
    from new;
    quit;

    %if &nbr = 1 %then %do ;
        data master;
        set new;
        run;
    %end; 
    %if &nbr > 1 %then %do ;
        data master;
        set master new ;
        run;
    %end ;
%mend;

/* concatenate datasets */
data runthis ;
set datasetNames ;
call execute('%catdat('||datasetname||','||_n_||')');
run;
```

Resolved: see Bob's comments below.

Comment: Is the code in your question just a example of your problem or is it real?  In other words, your code creates a variable "sku_prod_nbr" but then does not use it.

Comment: Sorry Bob, it is just an example. I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `PROC APPEND` instead of your "new" dataset; that will be much, much faster:

```
%macro DOIT;

proc sql noprint;
   select count(*) into : num_recs
   from datasetNames;
quit;

%do i=1 %to &num_recs;

data _null_;
  i = &i;
  set datasetNames point=i;
  call symput('ds_name',datasetname);
  stop;
run; /* UPDATE:  added this line */

%if &i = 1 %then %do;
/* Initialize MASTER with variables in the order you wish */
data master(keep=var1 var2 var3);
   retain var1 var2 var3;
   set libin.&ds_name;
   stop;
run;
%end;

proc append base=master data=libin.&ds_name(keep=var1 var2 var3);
run;

%end;

%mend DOIT;
```

`PROC APPEND` will add each dataset into your new "master" without rebuilding it each time as you are doing now.
This also avoids using `CALL EXECUTE`, removing that memory issue you were running into (caused by generating so much code into the execution stack).

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. Had to change the line set datasetNames point=i; to set datasetNames (firstobs = &i. obs = &i);, and dropped both of the stop statements because the were limiting the data read in, but besides that it worked great. Thank you again, this was a big help.

Comment: I omitted a `run` statement from the code; see the update; that may have caused your problem.  The `stop` statement is needed if using the `point` option in the first case.  Also, if you removed the `stop` statement from the "initialize MASTER" step, you will have duplicated the first dataset into MASTER.  The purpose was to create an empty dataset, so `stop` is required.

Comment: Oh, and I also added a `KEEP=` option in the initialize step, just to clearly name your variables.  And note:  that step was only needed because you asked to list variables in a particular order.  Read the documentation for `PROC APPEND` for more details.