# concatenate many tables in sas

Tags: sas, concatenation

This is to follow the post Efficiently concatenate many sas datasets: [Efficiently concatenate many sas datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442882/efficiently-concatenate-many-sas-datasets/13443205#13443205?newreg=f37f592f31764c76b42e78fdedd8f19b)

Well, I'm having a similar task, i.e to concatenate more than 10000 sas tables of the same structure. Each table consists of 2 rows and 13 columns and are named in sequential (data, data1, data 2, ...). All my tables are saved in an external drive: "D:\MySASfolder\". The concatenation using SET in datastep seems to be running out of memory and the proc append may be the solution. However, I've some difficulties to understand the code made by BellevueBob, in particular I'm not sure how the macro can revoke my 10000 data tables. Can anyone please help me to go through the code lines please. Many thanks, Mai

Comment: Bob's answer uses a simple macro `%do` loop to work through all the tables. Do a bit of background reading on SAS macros and then post another question if there's a part of it that you still don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently concatenate many sas datasets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442882/efficiently-concatenate-many-sas-datasets)

Comment: Did you try using member list in the SET statement? `data want; set data data1-data9999; run;`   Does it work with than many datasets referenced in a single SET statement?

Comment: Beyond the correct solutions below also consider the INDSNAME option that allows you to identify the input data set name.

Answer (score 0):

The other question actually isn't exactly the same as yours; it has a problem in that the data sets individually were being created on demand, and *then* appended.

If the datasets already exist, you have a far easier problem.

For example, let's make data1-data3 (which you've already done in a prior step) and then append them, using the single dash operator (which creates a new name list that contains all names in between the first and last name, in numeric order).

```
data data1;
  x=1;
run;

data data2;
  x=2;
run;

data data3;
  x=3;
run;

data want;
  set data1-data3;
run;
```

Of course, if you have `data` you will have to also add that.

```
data want;
  set data data1-data3;
run;
```

You can put a libname on this as well.

```
data want;
  set mylib.data1-mylib.data3;
run;
```

Comment: And - as a side note - this is a bad programming practice.  Don't create a bunch of effectively nameless datasets.  Instead, create ones with useful names - and if possible, append them together in the step they're created rather than making a bunch of datasets that will sit around.  You can avoid a lot of problems this way.

Comment: Yes, user667489 you are right. Mine is a bit different to Bob's task. So I got the code workable now:

Comment: Tom & Joe, with more than 10000 tables, SET is not workable at least with my PC, due to of the memory issue. The system has to read through all observations of the base and the new dataset, while proc append does not need to read through observations.